# How can I aggregate two List in some operation by using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have defined class StudentData that consist Name, Subject property which are Enum type and score as double. Some data are filled in the List structure StudentNameList and StudentDataList.

```
public class StudentData
{
    public StudentName Name { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public StudentData(StudentName name, Subject subject, double score)
    {
        Name = name;
        Subject = subject;
        Score = score;
    }
}

public enum StudentName
{
    Tom,
    Nikki,
    Benny
}

public enum Subject
{
    Math,
    Physic,
    History
}
    List<StudentName> studentName = new List<StudentName>();
    studentName.Add( StudentName.Benny);
    studentName.Add(StudentName.Nikki);
    studentName.Add(StudentName.Tom);

    List<StudentData> studentDataList = new List<StudentData>();

    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Benny, Subject.History, 85));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Benny, Subject.Math, 60));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Benny, Subject.Physic, 75));

    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Nikki, Subject.History, 65));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Nikki, Subject.Math, 70));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Nikki, Subject.Physic, 75));

    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Tom, Subject.History, 88));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Tom, Subject.Math, 90));
    studentDataList.Add(new StudentData(StudentName.Tom, Subject.Physic, 95));
```

There's Factor table defined below

```
        List<double> FactorTable = new List<double>();
        FactorTable.Add(1.05);
        FactorTable.Add(1.02);
```

What I want to achieve is to create a Dictionary<StudentName, Double> that value stores all weighted average score (by multiple all score with factor list) for that student. for example in Benny's case:

```
 Dictionary<StudentName, double> StudentDic = new Dictionary<StudentName, double>();
```

key: Benny
, value: (85 * 1.05) + (85 *1.02) + (60 * 1.05) + (60 * 1.02) + (75 * 1.05) + (75 * 1.02)

I thought it could be done by few aggregate Linq operation. however, It is not as easy to achieve when I come to implementation. What I do is below:

```
            foreach (var student in studentName)
        {
            var filterStudent = studentDataList.Where(s => s.Name == student);

            List<double> multipledResult = new List<double>();

            foreach (var s in filterStudent)
            {
                foreach (var f in FactorTable)
                {
                    multipledResult.Add(s.Score * f);
                }
            }
            StudentDic.Add(student, multipledResult.Average());
        }
```

What do I miss to simply the algorithm by using Linq operation. Could someone suggest if there's way to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pwilcox mentioned, `SelectMany` is the key to typical LINQ processing for your result, but I would suggest grouping first, then computing:

```
var StudentDic = studentDataList.GroupBy(s => s.Name, s => s.Score)
                                .ToDictionary(sg => sg.Key,
                                              sg => sg.SelectMany(s => FactorTable.Select(f => s*f)).Average());
```

Note that you could avoid `SelectMany` by summing the student's scores, multiplying the sum by each factor, sum that then divide by the count of scores times the count of factors.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a starting point:

```
var result = 
    studentDataList
    .SelectMany(sdl => FactorTable.Select(ft => new {
        sdl.Name, 
        aggScore = ft * sdl.Score
    }))
    .GroupBy(prod => prod.Name)
    .Select(g => new { 
        Name = (StudentName)g.Key, 
        wtAvg = g.Sum(x => x.aggScore) / g.Sum(x => x.ft)
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => (StudentName)x.Name, x => x.wtAvg);
```

The `SelectMany -> Select` approach gets you your sought product of every score by every weighting.  Then the chain creates a group for every person.  The final `Select` sums up all weighted products in the group.  The final line converts it to a dictionary if you really want that.

But don't forget that for a weighted AVERAGE, you also want to divide by the total possible weights.

It gives the result:

```
| Benny | 73.333... |
| Nikki | 70        |
| Tom   | 91        |
```

Benny's score is essentially arrived at by:

```
 var num = (85 * 1.05) + (85 *1.02) + (60 * 1.05) + (60 * 1.02) + (75 * 1.05) + (75 * 1.02);
 var den = 1.05 + 1.02 + 1.05 + 1.02 + 1.05 + 1.02;
 var result = num / den; // 73.33333......
```

Of course, if you really wanted the weighted sum, not the weighted average, then just delete the denominator in the final select method and rename from `wtAvg` to `wtSum`.

Comment: I get that Benny should have 75.9?

Comment: @NetMage.  The OP says she wants a "weighted average".  That to me indicates that the denominator should be the weightings (factors), not the count.  But of course if the OP ponders that and still doesn't feel that definition meets her needs then of course she could continue with using the count as the denominator or using `Average()`.